# unable to solve ODE with zdot function

Tags: ode, scilab

I have a problem with plotting RLC circuit with `zdot` function in Scilab

[image: RLC circuit].

I have worked out the analytical calculation:

```
Vin = ( VR/(s^2*L*C)+ VR/(s*R*C) + VR )   

    // R = 11 Ohm, R = 0.012 F, L = 1.5 H. f - 1e4
```

I'm trying to solve ODE above before plotting and it led me to

```
Vin = (s^2*VR + s*VR*(1/R*C) + VR/(L*C)) /s^2
```

i try to follow the manual in scilab for solving ode with `zdot` function :

```
function zdot=RLCsystem(t, y)
z1 = y(1); z2 = y(2);
// Compute input
Vin = A*sin(2*%pi*f*t);    // A = 1, f = 1e4 Hz
zdot(1) = z2; zdot(2) = (Vin - z1/(L*C) - z2/(R*C)) ;
endfunction
```

--*I dont know where the s^2 stand in this code / equation*

any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is properly a question about a mathematical formalism. What you call solution and equation is formulated in the Laplace space. Roughly, `s` stands for the differentiation operator, `1/s` for the integration operator. In a proper calculation there are also initial values involved.

Thus the ODE written in derivative notation is

```
VR'' + VR'/(R*C) + VR/(L*C) = Vin''
```

If the state vector `y` contains the function value and derivatives in increasing order, then the action of `s` is a shift in that vector, or the selection of the component corresponding to the power of `s`. Which is apparently done in the code.

Note that the code does not respect the second derivative of `Vin`. Correctly this would have to be

```
function zdot=RLCsystem(t, y)
z1 = y(1); z2 = y(2);
  // Compute input
  w = 2*%pi*f
  Vin = A*sin(w*t);    // A = 1, f = 1e4 Hz
  D2Vin = -A*w^2*sin(w*t)
  zdot(1) = z2; zdot(2) = (D2Vin - z1/(L*C) - z2/(R*C)) ;
endfunction
```

---

Other eliminations in the following confirmation calculation might result in first order systems that do not contain derivatives of the input voltage.

```
element laws:
  C*VC'=IC, VR = R*IR = VL = L*IL',
cell laws:
  IC = IL+IR, Vin = VC + VR
eliminate flows
  L*IC' = VR + L*IR'
  L*C*(Vin-VR)'' = VR + L/R*VR'
```